Inconsistent Data in Hazelcast IMap
I am using Hazelcast 5.3 and have set up a Hazelcast cluster with multiple nodes. I am using an IMap to distribute some data between my microservices. This IMap is backed by a MapStore with a write-behind configuration (write-delay-seconds greater than 0), but I assumed this wouldn't affect the in-memory visibility of the data (or does it?). I experience stale date from time to time.
Here is the issue I'm facing:
From time to time, a scheduler in microservice A puts some data into the map and then calls microservice B. Microservice B should be able to see the data that was put into the map by microservice A before it was called. Sometimes this works as expected, but other times microservice B doesn't see the new data and encounters stale data instead.
My understanding is that the write operation is performed on the partition key owner, and any subsequent reads should be directed to the same partition owner, ensuring the data read is always fresh. However, the observed behavior suggests otherwise.
Questions:
Is my understanding of how IMap works correct?
How can I achieve strong consistency in this scenario to ensure that microservice B always sees the fresh data put by microservice A?
Any insights or solutions to ensure consistent data visibility would be greatly appreciated!

I can give you a scenario where this may happen.

Assume that the HZ member performs a fresh start
Member receives a put operation request from Service A
Member loads the value from mapstore because it does not exist in memory
At this moment Service B performs a query and receives stale data
Service A's put operation resumes and replaces the stale data

Is it possible that your HZ member restarts ?

I have a kubernetes cluster with a scaling policy, so it's possible that some nodes may be created when this scheduler runs.
However, even if a fresh node starts, it should connect to the existing cluster and thereby find the data. The member would load the data from mapstore if the whole cluster was down, and there's nothing in memory, but this is not the case as i checked the logs.
I even checked the logs for this particular key that got stale data, and there is no "load" operation from mapstore

I even notice another strange thing. I put some data inside the map on some service and at a later time when i try to get the data on same service (and same pod), but a different thread i receive stale data
